# What is the unitary $1$-parameter group generated by a vector field on a manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, complex-geometry, lie-groups, flows

If $M$ is a (compact, Riemannian) manifold, and one complexifies its tangent bundle, is it possible to give a meaning to the "unitary group"-like expression  $t \mapsto \exp (\mathrm i t X)$ when $X$ is a *real* smooth vector field and $t \in \mathbb R$? I tried to think in terms of displacement along integral curves, but I don't see how a "real" curve could have an "imaginary" tangent. Should I maybe consider my curves to be defined on $\mathrm i \mathbb R$?

Comment: What about  if we  look at  $X$ as  an operator (the  derivational operator)?